# What language is this variable definition written in?

Tags: programming-languages

Anybody knows what language this variable definition is written in?

```
@article{Illana:2010gh,
      author         = "Illana, Jose I. and Lipari, Paolo and Masip, Manuel and
                        Meloni, Davide",
      title          = "{Atmospheric lepton fluxes at very high energy}",
      journal        = "Astropart.Phys.",
      volume         = "34",
      pages          = "663-673",
      doi            = "10.1016/j.astropartphys.2011.01.001",
      year           = "2011",
      eprint         = "1010.5084",
      archivePrefix  = "arXiv",
      primaryClass   = "astro-ph.HE",
      SLACcitation   = "%%CITATION = ARXIV:1010.5084;%%",
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's LaTeX, namely, a [BibTeX](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#BibTeX) file, used for bibliography management.